# Elements in a set that are not elements of another set (relative complement)

Tags: matlab, matrix, complement

In `matlab`, how can I implement the following?

Say that I have some set `A` and another set `B`, both of which have some elements. How can I write a function that returns only the values of `B` that are **not** in `A` (relative complement of A in B `B\A`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)

```
dif = setdiff( A, B )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I need the elements in `B` that are not in `A`, I should write `setdiff(B,A)`, right?

Comment: @Med-SWEng it appears as if you are right.