# Deleting the array elements from another array elements

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the following

```
A = [1 2 3]
```

and

```
Z = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

how do I remove the values of  A from Z, to get

Z = [4 5 6]

in Matlab?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802276/matlab-arrays-operation/5805213),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758240/in-matlab-how-can-i-fetch-all-the-element-in-a-but-not-in-b/17758247),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129533/how-to-get-the-elements-from-one-vector-that-arent-in-another-vector/10129588),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770613/elements-in-a-set-that-are-not-elements-of-another-set-relative-complement/14770638),[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241401/how-to-remove-specific-values-from-a-vector-in-matlab/15241462)...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>> Z(ismember(Z,A))=[]

Z =

     4     5     6
```

Or Simply,

```
>> Z = setdiff(Z,A)

Z =

     4     5     6
```